# NetworkX Get Degree of Node with Weights Applied

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I'm using NetworkX to create a weighted graph (not a digraph).  Each node has a node name and a number of edges that have a weight.  The weights are always positive, non-zero integers.

What I'm trying to do is get a list of tuples where each tuple represents a node in the graph (by name) and the weighted degree of the node.

I can do something like this:

```
the_list = sorted(my_graph.degree_iter(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

But this doesn't appear to be taking the weighting of each node into account.  Each node may have a different weight for every edge (or they may be the same, there's no way to know).

Do I need to write a function to do this manually?  I've been coming through the NetworkX docs and am coming up empty on a built-in way to do this (but maybe I'm overlooking it).

If I have to write the function myself, I'm assuming I use the `size()` method with the `weight` flag set.  That seems to only give me the sum of all the weights in the graph though.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the Graph.degree() method with the weight= keyword like this:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_edge(1,2,weight=7)

In [4]: G.add_edge(1,3,weight=42)

In [5]: G.degree(weight='weight')
Out[5]: {1: 49, 2: 7, 3: 42}

In [6]: G.degree(weight='weight').items()
Out[6]: [(1, 49), (2, 7), (3, 42)]
```

Comment: Does it work for DiGraphs in_degree and out_degree? Is it possible to use a function of node or edge data as weight?